# memory allocation and copy constructor on struct

Tags: c++

I'm just trying this out of curiosity. I have a struct with a constructor and a copy constructor and trying to initialize the struct using the copy constructor in the main, while at the same time within the main, implementing memory allocation to the pointer to a struct. Copy construct initialization works alright, but when I try to free it before the main return, it causes an assertion error in the heap.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>

    typedef struct tagInfo
    {
        int iX;
        int iY;

        tagInfo() {};

        tagInfo(int x, int y)
            : iX(x), iY(y) {};

        ~tagInfo() {};

    }INFO;

    int main (void)
    {
        INFO* pInfo = (INFO*)malloc(sizeof(INFO));

        pInfo = &INFO(10, 10);

        free(pInfo);

        return 0;
    }
```

How can I safely free the above pointer without causing assertion errors?

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is not valid C code!

Comment: Seeing that it's C++, you should use `new`/`delete`. In addition to that - storing a memory address of a temporary, and then using it (in `free`) is UB (nevermind creating a memory leak by not freeing `malloc`ed space).

Comment: You are making a mess by mixing C idioms into C++ code without a clear understanding of the implications. The way to learn C++ well is not by trial and error, but by starting at the bottom, and approaching it without bias from previously learned languages. [Pick a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for beginners and take it step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the basic misunderstanding is that a copy constructor does not copy the contents of one object into an (already existing) other object of the same type, but rather generates a new object, which is initialized based on the contents of the object to be copied from.

In your code, you reserve memory for an object of type `INFO` using `malloc` and let `pInfo` point to that memory.

Next, with `pInfo = &INFO(10, 10)` you instantiate a new object of type INFO on the stack (not on the heap), and let `pInfo` point to the memory address of this object (which is on the stack!). BTW, you loose the reference to your `malloc`-ed memory, as pointer `pInfo` does not point to the `malloc`-ed address any more, but on the new object.

`free(pInfo)` is critical, as you free a memory address which has not been allocated with `malloc` before.

Actually, you should do the following:

```
INFO* pInfo = new INFO(10, 10);
...
delete pInfo;
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the type of answer I was looking for! I know I should use new delete in a C++ code, but I just wanted to try it out using malloc and free, and compare. Thanks for being cool!

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` and `free` should not be used in C++, as they do not deal with construction/destruction of objects.

---

In modern C++ you should use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if you want to model *unique ownership*, or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if you want to model *shared ownership* - these are called *"smart pointers"* and provide a safe way of managing dynamic memory that automatically deals with deallocation/destruction. Example:

```
int main (void)
{
    auto pInfo = std::make_unique<INFO>(10, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

---

If you really want to go down the road of manual memory management, you must use `new` *(for allocation+construction)* and `delete` *(for deallocation+destruction)*. Example:

```
int main (void)
{
    INFO* pInfo = new INFO(10, 10);
    delete pInfo;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can do that with placement new, but it is highly discouraged:

```
// allocate
void* pInfoMem = malloc(sizeof(INFO));
// construct
INFO* pInfo = new(pInfoMem) INFO(10, 10);

// destruct
pInfo->INFO::~INFO();
// free
free(pInfoMem);
```

But then you need to manually call the destructor before the freeing.

It is much easier to just do (as other answers mention):

```
INFO* pInfo = new INFO(10, 10);
delete pInfo;
```